# I can't generate ejbDeploy with Bean Validation

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, websphere, bean-validation

I can't generate the folder ejbDeploy when I am using Bean Validation Annotations. My project use EJB 2.1 and JEE 7 with IBM Websphere Application Server 9. I tried to use Bean Validation in 1.1.0.FINAL and 2.0.0FINAL, but when I am generate the ejbDeploy, I get the following [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWCkp.png).

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Why don't you take a look at [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I think it could be useful for you and the community. Please, include the error in the question and please format the question.

Comment: Thank you @FrancescoLucianò, the error image is in the answer.

Comment: I think it could be better for you to copy the error or include the image if you want to have an answer...

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests your application indirectly references the class `com.ibm.wsspi.cluster.Identity`, so that class will need to be added to the classpath for the ejbDeploy step.  The ejbdeploy command does have a `-cp` option for this purpose.  That particular class is made available in the WebSphere thin client JARs. For example, if this is a JAX-WS application, then you might include `<WAS_INSTALL>/runtimes/com.ibm.jaxws.thinclient_9.0.jar` to the ejbdeploy classpath.

Alternatively, beginning with WebSphere Application Sever v9.0.5.0 the EJBDeploy step is no longer required if the application does not contain EJB Entity beans. The deployment artifacts will be generated for you dynamically at runtime, as needed. Note that since your application does include remote EJB interfaces, you may still need to generate RMI Stub classes if using a thin client. The Stub classes may be generated using RMIC from the JDK (with the -iiop option s) or the createEJBStubs command from WebSphere.